# Intellij IDEA imports wrong RxJS classes

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA to develop my angular project. When use classes from various libraries, IDEA adds import statements for me.

But, when adding RxJS classes, IDEA adds some imports incorrectly. For an example IDEA adds:

```
import {first} from "rxjs/internal/operators";
```

instead of

```
import {first} from "rxjs/operators";
```

And

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";
```

instead of

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
```

Although the import is incorrect, the behavior of the wrongly imported class is almost the same as the actual one, and only fail in some situations. So, sometimes it is hard to understand what is going wrong.

Is there any way I can instruct IDEA to import the correct classes?

Comment: Why can't you try Visual Code IDE?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya I could, but IDEA works well for many other languages I use and I like the consistency of features across all my development. So, using another IDE just for Angular seems too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please upgrade to 2018.1.2 or higher - [WEB-32299](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32299) is fixed there.
If this doesn't help, please remove `rxjs` from **Do not import exactly from:** field in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports**

Comment: It worked for `Observable`, but it didn't change `import {first} from "rxjs/internal/operators";`.

Comment: what IDEA version do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-181.4203.550, built on March 27, 2018

Comment: please try upgrading; https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32299 is fixed in recent update

Comment: idea 2019.1 issue is reproduced